# The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, scikit-image

When running:

```
from skimage import data
```

in jupyter notebook I always get the error : "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"

I use: 
Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)
Python 3.5.2
scikit-image 0.12.3 np111py35_1

When I run a notebook with python 2.7 kernel it goes fine with no error.

So I guess there is a compatibility issue?
But I need to use python 3.5, any suggestion?

Comment: Can you try the import in a standard Python console and see what happens?

Comment: I got a much more explicit error message:  
  `Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx.so or libmkl_def.so`

Comment: version installed:  
  
mkl                           11.3.3                   0    
mkl-service               1.1.2                    py35_2

Comment: Try starting Jupyter with the `--debug` flag; hopefully it will print out information about where the kernel is crashing.

Comment: thanks @StefanvanderWalt for the suggestion, problem solved

Answer (score 6):

Problem solved with: `conda update mkl`

working versions: 
mkl 2017.0.1 0
mkl-service 1.1.2 py35_2