# I can't import Keras in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, keras, jupyter-notebook

When I run `import keras` in the Jupyter Notebook cell, it crashes with the following message:

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Keras                  2.2.0

jupyter                1.0.0
jupyter-client         5.2.3
jupyter-console        5.2.0
jupyter-core           4.4.0
jupyterlab             0.32.1
jupyterlab-launcher    0.10.5

Python                 3.6.6

Console import log

```
kraamis@debian [~]$ python3
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jun 27 2018, 14:44:17) 
[GCC 8.1.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Using TensorFlow backend.
Illegal  instruction
```

tensorflow             1.9.0
tensorflow-gpu         1.9.0
tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.1

Comment: Have you tried restarting the whole jupyter notebook. Also please check, if importing keras works in your python console.

Comment: Restart notebook did not help. Reboot computer did not help too

Comment: console log added

Comment: what version of tensorflow are you using?

Comment: kraamis@debian [~]$ 
tensorflow             1.9.0      
tensorflow-gpu         1.9.0      
tensorflow-tensorboard 1.5.1

Comment: Can you please try `jupyter notebook --debug` and see if there are any helpful error. While starting the jupyter notebook.

Comment: Only fontconfig error 

Full starting log - https://pastebin.com/rfEvZYEY

Comment: I hope you're not inside the virtualenv are you?

Comment: No, I don't use virtualenv.

Comment: Aslo I would like you to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022997/jupyter-the-kernel-appears-to-have-died-it-will-restart-automatically.

Comment: I install `mkl`, but it's did not help

Comment: In case you don't have any error message in the jupyter notebook console, before it dies, can you please tell me a bit about what you're doing, are you just doing `import keras` and it just dies out.

Comment: Yes, I only import keras. One string in one cell

Comment: When it crashed, there should be something in your jupyter console, can you please check once.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand what you meant

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/HvMl20It.png something like this I meant. That is available on your terminal when you did `jupyter notebook` to start your notebook.

Comment: log after import keras and died of kernel https://pastebin.com/4JvEB8cb

Comment: there seems really nothing. And I can't reproduce it, Maybe you want to try and see the different version of keras. Only the further debug message could have helped but there seems really nothing.

Comment: In any case, thanks. I will think and if I find something, I will write here an answer. Judging by the search in Google - this is a common problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal instruction (core dumped) after running import tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094597/illegal-instruction-core-dumped-after-running-import-tensorflow)

Comment: This is a well known problem in TensorFlow due to the default builts using AVX. Please see the link in the duplicate question for alternatives.

Comment: Yes, I have a fairly old computer. Installing the old version of tensorflow helped to get rid of the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my obsolete processor did not support AVX. It was necessary to install the version of tensorflow no older than 1.5