# The kernel appears to have died

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have ran into `Kernel Restarting` problem after running this code, and have no idea what could be wrong:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')

df.fillna(value = {'Unnamed:12': 0, 
                   'Unnamed:13': 0,
                   'Unnamed:14': 0}, inplace = True)

# X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])
X = df.iloc[:, 1:12].values
y = df.iloc[:, 1].values

#encoding categorical data into dummy

#encoding independante var
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 10] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 10]) #dummy quantity
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [10])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
#etc for each dummy

#encoding dependant var
labelencoder_y = LabelEncoder()
y = labelencoder_y.fit_transform(y)
```

and i get window with this **error message**:

```
Kernel Restarting
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

I saw another similar problem and try solution from it:

[Jupyter | The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically |](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022997/jupyter-the-kernel-appears-to-have-died-it-will-restart-automatically).

- `conda update mkl`  - do not help
- `conda install numpy` - do not help too
- RAM usage `6.3/16 Gb`

I also read this topics, but do not get solution:

1. https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2784
2. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9829
3. https://www.kaggle.com/product-feedback/41221

What is strange i did the same transformation with another dataset and everything was just fine.