# Jupyter notebook error! kernel died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-console

ERROR: **The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically. This is specific to few lines of code**

When I try `print(3)` I see the output in the console as `3` but when I try to run, following code it gives me an error. It was working perfectly and all of sudden throwing these weird errors.

I tried restarting and reinstalling and upgrading all the libraries but nothing works.

```
import numpy as np

versicolor_petal_length = np.array([4.7,  4.5,  4.9,  4.,  4.6,  4.5,  4.7,  3.3,  4.6,  3.9,  3.5,
                                    4.2,  4.,  4.7,  3.6,  4.4,  4.5,  4.1,  4.5,  3.9,  4.8,  4.,
                                    4.9,  4.7,  4.3,  4.4,  4.8,  5.,  4.5,  3.5,  3.8,  3.7,  3.9,
                                    5.1,  4.5,  4.5,  4.7,  4.4,  4.1,  4.,  4.4,  4.6,  4.,  3.3,
                                    4.2,  4.2,  4.2,  4.3,  3.,  4.1])

versicolor_petal_width = np.array([1.4,  1.5,  1.5,  1.3,  1.5,  1.3,  1.6,  1.,  1.3,  1.4,  1.,
                                   1.5,  1.,  1.4,  1.3,  1.4,  1.5,  1.,  1.5,  1.1,  1.8,  1.3,
                                   1.5,  1.2,  1.3,  1.4,  1.4,  1.7,  1.5,  1.,  1.1,  1.,  1.2,
                                   1.6,  1.5,  1.6,  1.5,  1.3,  1.3,  1.3,  1.2,  1.4,  1.2,  1.,
                                   1.3,  1.2,  1.3,  1.3,  1.1,  1.3])


def pearson_r(x, y):
    """Compute Pearson correlation coefficient between two arrays."""
    # Compute correlation matrix: corr_mat
    corr_mat = np.corrcoef(x, y)

    # Return entry [0,1]
    return corr_mat[0, 1]


# Compute Pearson correlation coefficient for I. versicolor: r
r = pearson_r(versicolor_petal_length, versicolor_petal_width)

# Print the result
print(r)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter | The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically |](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022997/jupyter-the-kernel-appears-to-have-died-it-will-restart-automatically)

Comment: I tried that solution, its not working.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you tell me what is the capacity of your ram, because sometimes memory can become a bottleneck.

Comment: 8GB RAM and my machine is Macbook 2017 model