# Error: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Even with this simple code in Jupyter Notebook, I got an error as "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

How can I solve it?

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

X = range(0,100)
Y = [ math.sin(0.2 * x) for x in X ]

plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022997/jupyter-the-kernel-appears-to-have-died-it-will-restart-automatically). It could be similar in having to reinstall something.

Comment: [176 possible duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+kernel+appears+to+have+died.+It+will+restart+automatically) are available in the search facility.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question, thank you guys who answered for me.
I just needed to update some packages. For me, it was matplotlib and math.
Firstly I tried to forth update anaconda but it took long time and never finished even I wait 2 days. Then I realised that I just need to update what I need.